# Mac OS X "Revert Changes" usage/syntax in dialog?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

The use of "Revert Changes" always throws me off and I was wondering if this usage/syntax is actually correct.

It seems to me that technically speaking, when you select that you're not actually reverting *changes* per se, but reverting *the document* back to its state before changes were made.

Shouldn't that button label just be "Revert?"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct - it's the document that is reverted, not the changes.

In software design there is often a balance between grammatical correctness and simplicity/space usage.  In this case it seems like they could satisfy both these requirements by simply relabelling the button "Undo changes", but if the language of "reverting changes" has been used elsewhere then it may just be that it's kept for consistency's sake.

I think "Undo changes" is preferable to just "Revert" as a button label, but we're getting into https://ux.stackexchange.com/ territory now.

Comment: Agree. Perhaps they could have done something like "Revert Back" or "Revert to Original".

Answer (score 0):

Using the parallel terms "Save Changes" and "Revert Changes" makes it clear that these two actions are opposites.

Even if not strictly correct, it's easy to understand.

And as Max Williams says, it's shorter and saves space. Plus, users often have short attention spans. The fewer words you can use, the better.